# Dynamic system show that it has only one equilibrium point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

I have the following dynamic system $A\cdot\ddot{x}+B\cdot\dot{x}+ C\cdot x=0 $ and A,B,C are positive definite matrices.
I have to show that it has only one equilibrium point and that this point is asymptotically stable. Any help will be appreciated!

UPDATE
Following the comment about treating A,B,C as scalars
$\dot{x_1}=x_2 = f_1(x_2)\\
\dot{x_2}=(-B\cdot x_2-C\cdot x_1)/A = f_2(x_1,x_2)$
$\longrightarrow \dot{x}=A(x)|_{x=0} \cdot x \\ $

$ A(x)=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_2} \\
\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_2} \\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
-C/A&-B/A\\
\end{bmatrix}$
$det(A-\lambda\cdot I)= 0 \longrightarrow det(\begin{bmatrix}
-\lambda & 1\\
-C/A& -\lambda -B/A\\
\end{bmatrix}) =0 \longrightarrow \lambda^2+\lambda B/A+C/A=0$\

But I don't seem to get any idea on how to generalize it.

Comment: Here's a place to start: start with the case where $A,B,C,x$ are scalars and see if you can generalize your approach.

Comment: I followed your advice(see updated post) but I don't know how to generalize it or prove it

Answer (score 1):

At an equilibrium point you get $\dot x=0$ and $\ddot x=0$, so the remaining condition is $Cx=0$, now apply that $C$ is s.p.d.

For the normalization use $\tilde B=A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2}$ and $\tilde C=A^{-1/2}CA^{-1/2}$ so that with $y=A^{1/2}x$ you get a system
$$
\ddot y+\tilde B\dot y+\tilde Cy=0
$$
with still s.p.d. coefficient matrices. Then try to conclude that any exponential basis solution $ve^{\lambda t}$ needs to have $\lambda$ real and negative, or possibly complex with negative real part.

Comment: Thank you! How can i conclude the last part?

Answer (score 0):

I would start by calling $x=x_1$ and $\dot{x}=x_2$. Then you can rewrite the ODEs as:
\begin{equation}
\begin{matrix}
\dot{x_1}&=&&x_2\\
A\dot{x_2}&=&-Cx_1&-Bx_2
\end{matrix}
\end{equation}

or even:
\begin{equation}
\dot{\left[
\begin{matrix}x_1\\
x_2
\end{matrix}
\right]}
=
\left[
\begin{matrix}
0&I\\
-A^{-1}C&-A^{-1}B
\end{matrix}\right]
\left[\begin{matrix}
x_1\\
x_2
\end{matrix}\right]
\end{equation}
Then, the equlibria will be when $\dot{\left[\begin{matrix}x_1\\x_2\end{matrix}\right]}=\mathbf{0}$. That means, $0=x_2=\dot{x}$ and $0=-A^{-1}Cx_1=-A^{-1}Cx$ then you can apply that $A$ and $C$ are positive definite to find a value for $x$.

Now, to prove its stability we need to inspect the eigenvalues of $\left[\begin{matrix}
0&I\\
-A^{-1}C&-A^{-1}B
\end{matrix}\right]$.

$\lambda=\mathrm{zeros}(\left|\begin{matrix}
sI&-I\\
A^{-1}C&sI+A^{-1}B
\end{matrix}\right|)=\mathrm{zeros}(s^2I+A^{-1}Bs+A^{-1}C)$, using the fact that $A$, $B$ and $C$ are positive definite and using from [Routh-Hurwitz criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routh%E2%80%93Hurwitz_stability_criterion):

> The second-degree polynomial, $P(s)=s^{2}+a_{1}s+a_{0}$ has both roots in the open left half plane (and the system with characteristic equation if and only if both coefficients satisfy $a_{i}>0$.

we can finally tell if its stable or not.

Comment: Thank you! How can i prove that A^−1B  and A^−1C are > 0 so that the criterion is valid?

Comment: @Mpessy : You can't, because in general that is not the case. Thus the construction with the square root in my answer, $zeros(\det(s^2I+A^{-1}Bs+A^{-1}C)) = zeros(\det(s^2I+A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2}s+A^{-1/2}CA^{-1/2}))$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thank you but i still can't understand how I can prove that is stable from here..

Answer (score 0):

If $x_1$ and $x_2$ are equilibrium points then

$$
\cases{
C\cdot x_1 = 0\\
C\cdot x_2 = 0
}\Rightarrow C\cdot(x_1-x_2)=0
$$

but due to the nature of $C$ follows $x_1-x_2=0\Rightarrow x_1 = x_2$